# Nonconvex optimization with linear constraints

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, non-convex-optimization

Which algorithms are suitable for solving problems of the form
$$
\min_x \lbrace f(x) \; | \; Ax \leq b \rbrace
$$
with nonconvex, differentiable obfective $f$. Unfortunately, $f$ cannot be assumed to be differentiable twice. I am also interested in the case where $f$ has Lipschitz continuous gradients.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: Be aware that global minima may be out of reach.

Here are two possibilities that come to mind:

1. If you have differentiability, you may use **projected gradient descent**: Start with an initial guess $x_0$ that fulfills $Ax_0\leq b$, do a gradient descent step for $f$ and project the result back to the constraint set $Ax\leq b$ and iterate. You may need to control the stepsize to ensure descent and convergence.
2. Another approach (which gives a descent method in all cases) it what has been called **"$\eta$-trick"** (see [here](https://francisbach.com/the-%CE%B7-trick-or-the-effectiveness-of-reweighted-least-squares/)). The idea is to write the non-convex function as a minimum of a family of quadratic functions of the form $\tfrac{x^2}{2\eta} + h(\eta)$ i.e. $f(x) = \inf_{\eta>0} \tfrac{x^2}{2\eta} + h(\eta)$. If you find some $h$ which does that you can minimize with the respect to $x$ and $\eta$ alternatingly in a simple way…